# Excel VBA - Inserting 1000 rows at a time to sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm using the VBA code below to import data from my Excel table to SQL server. The code is inserting one row at a time and my tables contains thousands of rows.

To improve the speed of the import I want to import 1.000 rows at a time. How can I modify the code to insert 1.000 rows for each excecution?

I am not very skilled within VBA and found the code on this URL: http://tomaslind.net/2013/12/26/export-data-excel-to-sql-server/

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MSI\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=ExcelDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            sCustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
            sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            conn.Execute "insert into dbo.CustomersStage (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName) values ('" & sCustomerId & "', '" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop

        conn.Execute "EXEC dbo.MergeCustomers"

        MsgBox "Customers imported."

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: why dont you convert the file to .csv and use BULK INSERT to insert the data INTO SQL Server? Or that is NOT an option for you.

Comment: Hi. The issue with BULK INSERT is that the insert vba will be used by multiple users in our organization and our security settings on local computers stops this. So unfortunately this is not an option in this case. But I will use it I can bend the rules for myself.

Comment: if your org has MS Teams why not collab through there and send you e.o.b. Final files from each dept/user/etc . And you can convert it to CSV and upload to server. Strd etl lags apply. Data will be available am hrs or before business starts next day.

Answer (score 2):

Great point!  Bulk Insert is the fastest option out there.  You can use Excel for this, of course, but that's a very, very, very sub-optimal solution.  If you just want to get it done quickly, and easily, save the Excel file as a CSV file, and run the code below.

```
BULK INSERT listcustomer
FROM 'c:\your_file.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
GO
```

If Bulk Insert is not an option for you, consider the two solutions below.

Either.

```
Sub UpdateTable()
    
    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
    Dim objfl As Variant
    Dim rngName As Range

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Excel_to_SQL_Server.xls"

    Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        
    Set rngName = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))
    rngName.Name = "TempRange"
    strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName

    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
        
    nSQL = "INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Your_Server_Name;Database=[Northwind].[dbo].[TBL]]"
    nJOIN = " SELECT * from [TempRange]"

    cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN
    MsgBox "Uploaded Successfully"
    wbkOpen.Close
    Set wbkOpen = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

Or.

```
Sub InsertInto()
    
    'Declare some variables
    Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
    Dim cmd As adodb.Command
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    'Create a new Connection object
    Set cnn = New adodb.Connection
    
    'Set the connection string
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Your_Server_Name;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    
    'Create a new Command object
    Set cmd = New adodb.Command
    
    'Open the connection
    cnn.Open
    'Associate the command with the connection
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    
    'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    
    'Create the SQL
    strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = 2013-01-13 WHERE EMPID = 2"
    
    'Pass the SQL to the Command object
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
    
    'Open the Connection to the database
    cnn.Open
    
    'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
    cmd.Execute
    
    'Close the connection again
    cnn.Close
    
    'Remove the objects
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortenately our local security settings stops this option. Otherwise it would have been a good solution.

Comment: I just updated my original post.  Looping through the record set will NOT be faster.  There is no point in doing this task in chunks of 1000.  That's only for VERY large data loads where everything can't be stored in memory in one go.

Comment: Thanks for you first example. I had to make the insert something more like: INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Your_Server_Name;Database=Northwind].[TBL]

Answer (score 0):

> To improve the speed of the import I want to import 1.000 rows at a time. How can I modify the code to insert 1.000 rows for each excecution?

Lots of ways, but none easy from VBA.  Start by just using a transaction, or loading into a temp table.  The way you're currently doing it requires the log file to be flushed after each insert, which is probably most of your elapsed time.  Something like:

```
    conn.Execute "begin transaction"

    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        sCustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

        '... set parameter values 

        conn.Execute "insert into dbo.CustomersStage (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName) values (@CustomerId, @FirstName, @LastName)"



        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    conn.Execute "commit transaction"
```

Comment: I think you should at least add a warning about possible SQL Injection and usage of parametrized query.

Comment: We have done this in the past, doing 1000 X single row INSERT will take a very long time. You must try as possible to split into batches, 50 records/time, using the SQL Statement like this 'INSERT INTO TABLE (COLDEFS..) VALUES (ROW1...),(ROW2...)...(ROW50)'

Comment: 1000 single-row inserts should take just a few seconds, with the transaction and a SQL Server on your local network.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I know I recently implemented this to get around an issue with Access capping to 1000 rows/records. The quickest thing I could think of was to just iterate through the recordset one row at a time. I know using 32-bit Access it takes at least a minute to insert 1000+ rows into a SQL Server database on the same network. I can't think of (or don't want to) split the insert into chunks so I'm exploring methods of just replacing the system/program in Access with a C# application to `BULK INSERT` the local recordset.